# How to change loop condition variable within loop in python

Tags: python, loops, scope, boolean

I have a function-scoped boolean variable `bool_var` and I want to loop while `bool_var` is False. In the loop, I want to set `bool_var` equal to the return value of either `functionA()` or `functionB()` as so:

```py
def func():
   bool_var = False
   while bool_var is False:
      if something:
         bool_var = functionA()
      else:
         bool_var = functionB()
```

However, the `bool_var = function()` parts are treated as a new variable (the IDE says `bool_var` is not used) and thus the loop condition is not properly updated each time.

I have 2 questions about this: How do I fix/get around this and why does python want to initialize `bool_var` as a new local variable? I know it's a dynamically typed language but it feels like in a simple case like this it adds unnecessary (and unwanted) flexibility.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've shown (aside from the unorthodox test; use `while not bool_var` instead). Either your real code is different, or you can ignore the IDE's warning.

Comment: @chepner I was curious if you could do that like in Java, thanks. It seems weird that Pycharm wouldn't recognize that as the function scoped variable and not the one inside the if statement.

Comment: @chepner Turns out I actually had the `while not bool_var` part in my code I must've blanked when I wrote it!